# How do i fix the Linq error on WebGL build?

Tags: c#, linq, unity-game-engine, webgl, unity-webgl

I have an interesting issue on WebGL build. My game works well in editor but after build WebGL it does not working properly and getting crash. The error says like "you are using linq.first but your data is null" and I did not use the First() function any of my scripts. Please help I couldn't find anything about this error.

i did not use the "First" function. Project works on editor, android, ios but not work at webgl. I do not know which script causes this error.

```
  at System.Linq.Enumerable.First[TSource] (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] source) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
 
(Filename: currently not available on il2cpp Line: -1)
```

Comment: Well a) how about rather including the actual error message? Then b) show us your code please .. and c) if something is `null` - which is what the error already tells you - then try to find out why

Comment: 1. Narrow down where the error occurs
2. Introduce try-catch
3. Log all information, all values of variables
4. Analyze and fix

Answer (score -1):

If you're using `FirstOrDefault()` method please change all of it to `SingleOrDefault()` and create your logic this way(change necsessarily), otherwise this issue might be related of your UnityEditor version.

Comment: i didn't use FirstOrDefault() method. Thats because i couldn't solve the problem.

Comment: This won't help at all. `SingleOrDefault` tries to read *two* items to ensure there's only a single result